# Cannot take address of rvalue error in a recursive function for a binary tree

Tags: c++11, pointers, object, xcode7, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a recursive insert function for my binary search tree. However, I keep getting the following error "Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type Node*". I understand that if my pointer is NULL that taking the address of it would give me this error, but how would I go about mitigating this problem?

Note: The Node(data* _data) constructor sets the left and right pointer to NULL when an object is created.

Here is my code, I have commented the two lines that are producing the rvalue error. I am also using Xcode.

Thanks in advance.

```
class Node {
private:
data* data;
Node* left;
Node* right;

public:
Node(data* _data);

~Node();

Node* getLeft(); // gets the left immediate descendent of the Node.

Node* getRight(); // gets the right immediate descendent of the Node

data* getVal(); //returns pointer to data
};


class Tree {

private:
Node* root;
int nodeCount;
Node* placeNode(Node** root, data* data);

public:
Tree();

~Tree();

bool placeIn(data* newData); //placeIns node into ordered BST
};


bool Tree::placeIn(data* newData) {

return placeNode(root, newData); //placeIns newData object into BST
}


Node* Tree::placeNode(Node** root, data* data) {
//placeIns node into BST via in order traversal


if ((*root) == NULL) {
    return (*root) = new Node(data);
}


if ((*root)->getVal()->getName() == data->getName()) {
    cout << "Node exists" << endl;
    return NULL;
}

if ((*root)->getVal()->getName() > data->getName()) {
    placeNode(&(*root)->getLeft(), data); //Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type Node*
}

else {
    placeNode(&(*root)->getRight(), data); //Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type Node*
}

return NULL;
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile (due to non-question related issues) and you don't say what the error is, so it's quite difficult to help.   https://godbolt.org/g/RZFQXK

Comment: "rvalue error" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Code is just a simplified version of my program. I have edited the above which now states the error precisely.

Answer (score 0):

`getLeft()` and `getRight()` return rvalues, meaning they return a temporary object that is a copy of some other object. You can't take the address of a temporary.

If you *could* take the address of those temporaries, the `placeNode` function would not do anything useful, because it would set the temporary to the result of the `new Node(data)` expression, and then the temporary would vanish, leaking the memory of the new Node that you just created. The error is doing you a favour, by refusing to compile broken code.

If your intention is to set the member variables `left` and `right` to the new Node then you need to do that, not set some temporary copy of those variables. To do that you need to make `getLeft` and `getRight` return a reference or pointer to the member variables, not a copy of them. Either return the address of the member variable (instead of taking the address of the temporary copy), or for more idiomatic C++ return a reference to the member variables and change `placeNode` to take `Node*&` not `Node*`. Or provide `setLeft()` and `setRight()` member functions instead, and leave the getters unchanged.

There are still other errors in the code though, e.g. `return root = new Node(data)` won't compile, because `root` is a `Node**` not a `Node*` (did you mean to dereference it? If you make it a `Node*&` then you won't need to.)